# Undefined column when searching 2 columns concatenated into 1 in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

## Problem

For some reason I'm getting the error:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "full_name" does not exist
```

For the following query:

```
User.select("first_name || ' ' || last_name as full_name").where("full_name = ?", "Jon Snow")
```

Which converts into the sql query:

```
SELECT first_name || ' ' || last_name as full_name FROM \"users\" WHERE (full_name = 'Jon Snow')
```

## Goal

My intention is to be able to query by a users full name, but I don't want to split it out because this is used in a much larger query.

## Attempts

I've tried a many variations of using/not using the table name (`users`) around `first_name`, `last_name`, or `full_name` and also tried adding/removing quotes/parenthesis from various locations. I've found that if I query without a `where`, and then check what `full_name` is, it actually gathers it correctly. `Concat` also seems to yield the same error.

## Possible Solution

Instead of naming it, it looks like if I move the `concat` into the `where` call, it should work:

```
User.where("CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) = ?", "Jon Snow")
```

SQL:

```
"SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\" WHERE (CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) = 'Jon Snow')
```

It doesn't seem as convenient as using a named variable but maybe you just can't do that.

Comment: The WHERE clause is evaluated before the SELECT, i.e. at the time when aliases are not known yet. You cannot therefore use column aliases in WHERE clause. This problem was already known in the [twentieth century](http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/sql/node22.html);)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference aliases from the `SELECT` clause in the `WHERE` clause you need to do so using a subquery in `FROM`, e.g.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS full_name
  FROM some_table
  WHERE ...otherpredicates...
) x
WHERE full_name = 'Jim Bob';
```

Comment: The combination of your answer and the comment makes a lot of sense, I forgot the order of everything